# Google Cloud VM Shutdown by "Integrity Event"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

It seems like my Gooogle Cloud VM was shutdown by an "integrity event":

```
{
  "insertId": "3",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "lateBootReportEvent": {
      "policyEvaluationPassed": false,
      "policyMeasurements": [
        
      ],
      "actualMeasurements": [
        
      ]
    },
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent",
    "bootCounter": "3"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_instance",
    "labels": {
      "zone": "us-central1-a",
      "instance_id": "xxx",
      "project_id": "xxx"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-02-09T03:58:16.830409192Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/xxx/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-02-09T03:58:18.846995634Z"
}
```

Can those be prevented or even disabled somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> Can those be prevented or even disabled somehow?

The answer depends on what you mean. You are using a Shielded VM which protects you from:

- Prevent tampering with the guest VM image.
- Prevent altering sensitive crypto operations.
- Prevent exfiltrating secrets sealed in the vTPM
- Prevent modifying the system with UEFI drivers.
- Prevent modifying guest firmware.
- Prevent modifying the kernel.

Those actions will trigger an integrity event. To prevent an integrity event, do not modify the system.

Refer to **logName** for more information.

Note: **lateBootReportEvent** compares the original baseline to the latest boot sequence. The integrity policy baseline is used for comparison with measurements from subsequent VM boots to determine if anything has changed.

[What is Shielded VM?](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/shielded-vm)

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. To clarify my question: Can unexpected shudowns of the VM be prevented? As far as I understand, the integrity event caused the VM to restart which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @tiberiusj - That depends on the details. What caused the change to your system that required a reboot?